# Gitlab CI/CD using FTP for .NET Core

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to auto build, test and deploy my .NET Core app, and so far it builds and tests but it won't deploy. The Gitlab pipeline shows that the job succeeded but it didn't actually work. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /source

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x |  bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs


COPY ./src/*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY ./src/ ./

RUN dotnet publish "./Spa.csproj" --output "./dist" --configuration Release --no-restore

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /source/dist .

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php-cli

COPY deployment.ini /app
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Spa.dll"]
```

and this is what my .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like:

```
# ### Define variables
#
variables:
 OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: 'obj'    
 NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: '.nuget'
 SOURCE_CODE_PATH: 'src/'             

# ### Define stage list
stages:
 - build
 - test
 - deploy

cache:
 # Per-stage and per-branch caching.
  key: "$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" 
  paths:
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/project.assets.json'
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/*.csproj.nuget.*'
    - '$NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'
    - '**/node_modules/'

build:
  image: docker:stable
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/chinloyal/spa .
    - docker push  registry.gitlab.com/chinloyal/spa

tests:
  image: microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x |  bash -
    - apt-get install -y nodejs
  script:
    - dotnet test --no-restore Tests/

deploy:
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull registry.gitlab.com/chinloyal/spa
    - docker run --name spa -p 80:80 -d registry.gitlab.com/chinloyal/spa
  script:
    - docker exec -d spa curl -S "https://gitlab.com/chinloyal/ftp-deploy-tool/raw/master/deployment.phar" --output deployment.phar
    - docker exec -d spa bash -c "echo remote = $FTP_HOST >> deployment.ini"
    - docker exec -d spa bash -c "echo user = $FTP_USER >> deployment.ini"
    - docker exec -d spa bash -c "echo password = $FTP_PASSWORD >> deployment.ini"
    - docker exec -d spa php deployment.phar deployment.ini
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - master
```

This line `docker exec -d spa php deployment.phar deployment.ini` is the one that is suppose to upload the files from inside the docker container. But I believe that because Gitlab ends the process immediately after that line. Then the process inside the container just ends.

I've tried using the registry image (`registry.gitlab.com/chinloyal/spa`) as the image for deploy, but every time I try to use it, then it just starts running the project on Gitlab until it timesout or until I cancel it.

I only have ftp access to the server by the way, because it's a shared server. The ftp tool I'm using to deploy is [here](https://github.com/dg/ftp-deployment). I've tried it before so I know it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, all the `docker exec` commands used `-d` flag so I removed the `-d` flag so that gitlab would show the output of files being downloaded and uploaded. so I changes this `docker exec -d spa curl -S "https://gitlab.com/chinloyal/ftp-deploy-tool/raw/master/deployment.phar" --output deployment.phar` to `docker exec spa curl -S "https://gitlab.com/chinloyal/ftp-deploy-tool/raw/master/deployment.phar" --output deployment.phar`

I also changed `docker exec -d spa php deployment.phar deployment.ini` to `docker exec spa php deployment.phar deployment.ini`.

So before they were running in detached mode so because of that gitlab thought they had finished and just moved on to the next command, removing the `-d` flag lets gitlab wait.